# Javascript:Add Hours to Date

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I am new to Java scripting and trying the following code

```
        //get hours to be added
        var r=document.getElementById("select").value;
        //value of r can be 5 or 2.5 or so..
        var dt=new Date();
        var time=dt.getHours();
        var time2=dt.setHours(1);
        alert(time2);
```

But I get some long values like this **1398284822090** Isn't there a better way to add hours and than convert it back to standard format? Any documentation for further details will also be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: The value returned by [*setHours*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.34) is the new internal time value. Usually this value is ignored, the date object itself is mutated so just use that, i.e. do `alert(dt)`.

Answer (score 1):

The *long value* is a timestamp. Calling `setHours` actually changes the `dt` date, so you can simply:

```
dt.setHours(1);
alert(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt=new Date();
dt.setHours(1);
alert(dt);
```